# Syntax for definition

Tags: regex, msdn

What is syntax used in MSDN for definition and how to understand it?

```
connection-string ::= empty-string[;] | attribute[;] | attribute; connection-string
empty-string ::=attribute ::= attribute-keyword=attribute-value | DRIVER=[{]attribute-value[}]
attribute-keyword ::= DSN | UID | PWD | driver-defined-attribute-keyword
attribute-value ::= character-string
driver-defined-attribute-keyword ::= identifier
```

Is this some kind of regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

This is [Backus-Naur Form (BNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), a meta-language well suited to describing language productions.